# Where can I find android dial pad image assets to create a custom dialer app?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a custom dialer app for Android and need the buttons/assets in their normal and selected (when depressed a different color is presented).

Can someone please tell me if there is a place to find such assets.

Comment: Can't you just use regular buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can find the assets inside the SDK directory. On mac it will be `YOUR_SDK_DIR/platforms/android-(VERSION)/data/res`, where `VERSION` is the version of the SDK you want the drawables.

Comment: I think since Dialer.apk is not part of the system those buttons may not be in there. Is worth a check though.

Comment: Yep, you're right, there's just the icon for the dialer.
Doing a quick search on Google, I was able to found a dialer project that maybe can help since it has the drawables and stuff: https://bitbucket.org/dnaq/dialer2/src/f170814ddcda/res/layout/dialpad.xml

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers. I am looking for custom imagery but I may just need to work within the parameters of the dialer project.